# no such element exception error while looping through second iteration selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am trying to extract data through different links.
All the links are similar except at the end the id alone changes. That id is i in the below for loop.

```
for i in list:
driver.get(‘somelink’+i)
his=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/form/div/table/span[1]/div/span[1]/div[11]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[1]')
his.click()
```

So my question is during the first loop it went well but on the second loop no such element error occured. Excuse my formatting new here

Tried time sleep and all solutions in stackoverflow but didn't work. I cant share the website link sorry as its private

Comment: Is the element's property you declared - 'his' same in all the pages?

Comment: Yes its storing in his. @AbiSaran

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has different tools for waiting / sleeping.
In short there are explicit and implicit waits. Ignoring fluent waits as I never used them.

Simplified implicit is used when you are sure that the element will be there after some time. It is applicable to all elements.
So as an example you can implicit wait 10 seconds under the assumption that the necessary element is then there.
`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`

Explicit can be based on certain conditions, like is the element visible.
This is good for dynamic pages but only applicable to single elements.
So here you would wait until you element is clickable and specify a timeout period after an Exception is thrown if the element does not appear.
`WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "waitCreate")))`

`EC` are ExpectedConditions check them out to find what you need.

Comment: I tried all these didnt work